# Number of Subsets that Satisfies a Divisibility Condition

Tags: combinatorics

Here is an interesting question that I thought of:

> We call a subset $S$ of the positive integers *good* if for all $n \in S$, we have that $d \in S$ for all $d | n$. 
>   Find the number of good subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$.

If we let $f(n)$ be this number, we get $f(p) = 2f(p-1) - 1$ for primes $p$. But for non-prime $n$, it seems to difficult to connect it to earlier values of $n$.

Any solutions, suggestions, or comments would be appreciated

Comment: But we can have a subset like {1,2,3} which is not totally ordered

Comment: do you want exact answer or asymptotics?